# difference between throw an error and return an error in julia

Tags: error-handling, julia

those two pieces of code results in the same error thrown given a condition:

```
function f1(x)
  if x > 2
    return x
  else
    return error("x <= 2")
  end
end

function f2(x)
  if x > 2
    return x
  else
    throw(error("x <= 2"))
  end
end
```

both `f1` and `f2` errors when x <= 2, but i can´t find any differences in why prefer one over the another. going further, these 3 pieces of code return the same:

```
error(2)
throw(2)
throw(error(2))
```

is there any guides on how to use throw vs return an error directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`error` throws an error in itself. From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.error):

> `error(message::AbstractString)`
>
> Raise an ErrorException with the given message.

So there is no need to either return it (as in your `f1` function) or throw it yourself (as in `f2`); in both cases the exception will be thrown by `error` before your handwritten `return` or `throw` is even reached.

The same goes for your comparison between `throw(error(2))` and `error(2)`: the `throw` is useless here and these two expressions should do the same thing (even the stack trace is the same).

---

Regarding `error(2)` vs `throw(2)`, it indeed superficially looks like they do the same thing (with slightly different stack traces):

```
julia> error(2)
ERROR: 2
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::Int64) at ./error.jl:42
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[8]:1

julia> throw(2)
ERROR: 2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[10]:1
```

but this is only because the REPL pretty-prints the errors in ways that are indistinguishable in this case. In reality, `throw` raises exactly what you pass it as argument: the integer 2 in this case. Whereas `error` stringifies its argument and wraps it in an `ErrorException` object before raising it. This can be seen by catching the exception and `dump`ing it:

```
julia> try
         error(2)
       catch e
         dump(e)
       end
ErrorException
  msg: String "2"

julia> try
         throw(2)
       catch e
         dump(e)
       end
Int64 2
```

---

In conclusion, I'd say

- use `error` if you want to raise `ErrorException`s, which are generic exceptions accompanied by a message as a string. This is IMO mostly adequate when the error is destined to a human. If you do so, only call `error`; don't `return` or `throw` it.
- use `throw` when you want to control the type of exception raised. For example: `throw(BoundsError(my_array, idx))`. Such an exception might be easier to catch and programmatically handle in some function up the stack. Or it will perhaps at least convey a more specific message to a user if it is not caught.